# Want to synchronize two table in oracle without using DBMS_COMPARISON

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two identical tables in the database (Same column name, same data type). Table A and Table B.

A is the master table. Now i want to update the table B with the changes done in the master table A automatically at any point of time. How would i do that without using DBMS_COMPARISON

Comment: DML changes or DDL changes? Are you talking about adding columns or updating data in the table?

Comment: @Ben DML changes...I need to update the data in the table B